# Overwrite the input feature with the output feature with ArcPy

Tags: python, arcpy

Let's say that I have 4 features classe:

- `Layer1`
- `Layer2`
- `Layer3`
- `Layer4`

I want to erase my `LayerX` with all the `LayerY`where `Y<X`.
So for example the erase feature for the `Layer3` will be `Layer2` and `Layer1`.

I'm using the function `Erase_analysis`.

```
Erase_analysis (in_features, erase_features, out_feature_class)
```

I don't want to create tousand of new layers, so during my iteration I try to use the same input name and output name.

My code using arcpy:

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

for x in n:
    for y in n[:(x-1)]:
        arcpy.Erase_analysis('layer'+str(x), 'layer'+str(y), 'layer'+str(x))
```

But, and it was expected, the python consol give me this error

> Output Feature Class is same as Input Features, Failed to execute
>   (Erase).

Is there a solution using arcpy ?

Is there a more pythonic way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying your input to `in_memory`, prior to using Erase, should work:

```
for x in n:
    for y in n[:(x-1)]:
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('layer'+ str(x), "in_memory\layer" + str(x))
        arcpy.Erase_analysis("in_memory\layer" + str(x), 'layer'+ str(y), 'layer'+ str(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `arcpy.Delete_management` to delete the input after the erase. I also think merging the erasefeatures prior to erase will speed everything up:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\database.gdb'
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1
featurelist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for feature in featurelist:
    mergelist=[i for i in featurelist if int(i[-1])<int(feature[-1])]
    arcpy.Merge_management(inputs=mergelist, output=r'in_memory\merge')
    arcpy.Erase_analysis(in_features=feature, erase_features=r'in_memory\merge', 
                        out_feature_class='{0}_erased'.format(feature))
    arcpy.Delete_management(feature)
```