# Iterating through erase features while Input feature == output feature using ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, erase

I have a polygon which represents a large area. Smaller polygons should be used to erase pieces step by step from of the large area polygon.
For this purpose, I use the Model Builder in ArcGIS.

My setting (please have a look at the picture I attached)

- Iterator goes through a workspace where 'erase features' are stored and pass them to the 'erase tool'.
- 'erase too'l take the passed features as 'erase feature'.
- 'Input Feature' should be 'output feature' at the same time, because the process is used to delete small pieces of area from the 'input polygon'.

Problem: The tool delivers the message: "Output Feature Class is same as Input Features".

I tried to adapt this advice in [Overwrite the input feature with the output feature with ArcPy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261905/overwrite-the-input-feature-with-the-output-feature-with-arcpy), but storing the 'input feature' in in_memory causes the same message: "Output Feature Class is same as Input Features".

Is there a simple solution?

[image: Model]

Comment: Merging all erase features in the workspace and then do one erase is not an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by myself.

Using 'copy feature' to create an output which can be defined as input for the 'erase tool' works.

[image]